# The code is not iterating inside the ForEach statement

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am creating a tab bar view following the gist at the bottom.
Everything works fine except for the fact that when the index is changing the following inside the ForEach statement is not execute. So the content view doesn't change.

```
ForEach(views.indices) { i in
       self.views[i].view
          .opacity(self.selectedIndex == i ? 1 : 0)
       }
```

I have others solutions to achieve my goal but I'd like to know why the ForEach is not working as expected.
Any help apprecieated

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabView: View {
    var views: [TabBarItem]
    @State var selectedIndex: Int = 0

    init(_ views: [TabBarItem]) {
        self.views = views
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(views.indices) { i in   // it is not stepping into this when selectedIndex changes!!
                self.views[i].view
                    .opacity(self.selectedIndex == i ? 1 : 0)
            }
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.black.opacity(0.5), Color.black.opacity(0)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                            .frame(height: 49 + geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)

                        HStack {
                            ForEach(self.views.indices) { i in
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.selectedIndex = i
                                }) {
                                    VStack {
                                        if self.selectedIndex == i {
                                            self.views[i].image
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .padding(.top, 8)
                                        } else {
                                            self.views[i].image
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                                                .padding(.top, 8)
                                        }
                                        Text(self.views[i].title)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .font(Font.system(size: 12, weight: .bold))
                                            .opacity(0)
                                    }
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TabBarItem {
    var view: AnyView
    var image: Image
    var title: String

    init<V: View>(view: V, image: Image, title: String) {
        self.view = AnyView(view)
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    TabView([
      TabBarItem(view: FeedView(),
                 image: Image("house.fill"),
                 title: "Feed"),
      TabBarItem(view: SearchView(),
                 image: Image("loupe"),
                 title: "Explore"),
      TabBarItem(view: CreateView(),
                 image: Image("plus.circle"),
                 title: "Create"),
      TabBarItem(view: LoginView(),
                 image: Image("person.fill"),
                 title: "Profile"),
    ])
  }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/kishikawakatsumi/562028c46e7549aba658c88366417f6b

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI needs to know how it can identify each item uniquely otherwise it’s not able to compare view hierarchies to figure out what has changed and that's because you are missing the `id` inside of the `ForEach`.

```
ForEach(views.indices, id: \.self) { i in
   self.views[i].view
       .opacity(self.selectedIndex == i ? 1 : 0)
}
```

Personally I like how is explained in there:

- [working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/working-with-identifiable-items-in-swiftui)
- [how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach)